# im displaying individual product details by making an api call, all the product data is rendering correctly, except a sub array of imgs while mapping

Tags: reactjs, iteration, undefined, conditional-rendering

```
const proId = useParams();
    const ProductId = proId.id;
    const [proData, setProData] = useState({})
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${ProductId}`)
            .then(res => setProData(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [ProductId]);

    const { thumbnail, brand, description, images, price, rating, title } = proData;

    return (
        <div className='w-full p-4'>
            <div className="">
                <div className="md:flex justify-center items-center">
                    <img className='' src={thumbnail} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="pt-12 md:p-4 rounded-lg ">
                    <h1 className='text-4xl py-2'>{title}</h1>
                    <h3 className='text-xl font-semibold py-3'> <span className='text-blue-700'>Brand : </span> <span className='opacity-80'>{brand}</span></h3>
                    <p className=''>Description : </p>
                    <p className=''>{description}</p>
                    <h2 className=''>Price : <span className=''>{price} $</span></h2>
                    <p className="">Rating : <span className='opacity-80'>{rating}</span> ⭐</p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-8 p-4">
                    {
                            images.map((item, i) => (
                                <div key={`smi${i}`} className=""><img className='max-h-[200px]' src={item} alt={``} /></div>
                            ))
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when im trying to map the images[which is an array of imgs in the api response] using .map(), its throwing errors, saying cannot read properties of undefined, every other data renders perfectly but except this image array.can some one explain how can i render the images?

Comment: try optional chaining i.e or add a check before mapping i,e images?.length && map images?.map . images might be undefined and it might be possible there is not key of name images in some products.

Comment: @WasifAli Thank you so much! That helped. Can you please explain, what does the '?' at images?.length do and what is this process called?

Comment: My pleasure. 
The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object is undefined or null, it returns undefined instead of throwing an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining